# In which layer should live read models (projections) in DDD with Event Sourcing?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

In typical DDD architecture we have 3 layers:

**Domain** - no references

**Application** - it has reference to Domain layer

**Infrastructure** - it has reference to Domain layer

(+ Web / UI project)

Domain models live of course in Domain layer. But in which layer should live read models (projections) for read database, for example MongoDb?

Answer (score 7):

There's no written law that dictates in which project a read model should live. In my personal opinion, I think having a separate read model project has its benefits. With command query responsibility segregation things tend to get pretty confusing if the command-part of the application can access the query-part of the application. I think the two should be clearly separated.

I've spent some time working on an example project that demonstrates how to set up your DDD/ports-and-adapters/CQRS application. I've dropped the code on GitHub: https://github.com/appie2go/steal-this-code

I've also spent some time to explain the choices I've made in detail in the following articles:

- https://medium.com/@abstarreveld/implementing-dddomain-models-ports-adapters-and-cqrs-with-c-2b81403f09f7 and,
- https://medium.com/@abstarreveld/dddomain-models-ports-adapters-and-cqrs-reference-architecture-c-504817df65ec

Hope it helps!

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

Short answer, both Application Services (Application layer) and Repositories (Infrastructure layer) know about the READ models. The domain layer remains transparent to underlying persistence and loading mechanisms.

Long answer, the exact usage mechanism depends on how you use the read models. You could either be using them to construct objects used in your domain layer or more typically, only as responses to API queries.

**First case: Use Read Models as objects in the domain layer**

The Application service loads the READ model from the repository into the domain entity. It is the repository's responsibility to populate the READ model correctly into the domain entity. The repository is also responsible for transforming the domain entity into the WRITE model to persist in the primary database.

By the time you get to the Domain model, objects are already loaded into memory with the help of repositories. So the domain layer does not even know about the READ model and a WRITE model; it only deals with the domain entity.

**Second case: Use Read Models for storing pre-built responses to API queries**

This scenario is a more typical use of the READ models. Usually, there are more than one read models for the same Entity/Aggregate because they are custom-built for specific API requests.

In this case, we don't even touch the domain layer. The Application Service accepts the request, uses the READ model repository to load the object, and return a response to the application server.

Comment: In event sourcing, read models do not represent domain entities by definition. The only source of truth is the event stream of that entity.

Comment: Good point, @AlexeyZimarev. I should have mentioned I was talking about intermediate snapshots of data, capture from the event stream. Even then, you are right in saying read models do not play a role in the domain layer.

Comment: I can imagine that you use a read model as the data source for some domain service. It might not be ideal but still legit. That being said, I'd try to avoid using the read model as the main source of any kind of information to make decisions in the domain. The entity or aggregate needs to contain enough information to make that decision.

Comment: Agree. In all my implementations so far, read models have only been used for pre-prepared API responses. And more often than not, there are more than one read models for the same entity or aggregate. As I highlighted in my response, using read models in the First case is not a typical case, though it is possible. So we are in sync in our thought process.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, it doesn't really matter. There's no *default structure* for neither DDD-oriented implementation or event sourcing-oriented implementation.

You can perfectly have a single project if the system is small. If you want to keep your domain clean of external references - you can keep it in a separate project and take care of having zero references except for something you need to support the domain model basis, like entity base class and so on.

Read models and projections are completely orthogonal to the domain model and you usually need them for the query API or query services. You will benefit from keeping read models (documents in case of MongoDB) and projections in one place. You can either reference this project from your API project or keep the query API, query services, query models, read models and projections together.

Again, I would argue that such a thing as a "typical DDD architecture" doesn't exist, because DDD is not architecture to start with. Splitting projects is more a developer convenience and discipline concern and splitting the system is the architectural concern, which is not DDD-specific.

One thing that also comes to my mind is that if you *really* think DDD, you might first want to find out what is your context map, how many domain models you really need and maybe there you can find some ideas about separation, not based on technical concerns really.